# Network Manager v1.6

Tags: updates, network-manager

According to NetworkManager man on Ubuntu 16.04 (that I updated right now with apt-get update / upgrade), the NetworkManager version is 1.2.2.

I would like to use NetworkManager 1.4 or later (seems 1.6 is stable), because it allows automatic MAC spoofing:

- https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager
- https://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/tree/NEWS?h=1.6.2

How can I do this manually? Guess clone the NetworkManager git and run make on it? (I did not want to try before consulting others, don t want to break my internet connection)

Comment: I think it's unlikely NM will be backported, compare the current versions on 12.04 or 14.04

Comment: If done properly upgrading NM will not mess with apt-get update / upgrade later on. I removed the last two questions to prevent your question from bering closed as too broad and because they are answered in the comments, but you can undo my edit from your question's [revision history](http://askubuntu.com/posts/889120/revisions).